# xcode shortcut key import h file and add the Delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, shortcut

I am new iOS development but I know android at eclipse. For example I am lack a package, I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to import the package,if there is shortcut key at Xcode can help to import the `.h` file. Because sometimes I do not know my methods from which `.h` file.
you know when I add new Delegate to `.h` file,how to use shortcut key help me to add the need implement methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have that in Xcode, and honestly, at least in my perspective, I never really had the need to have it (and I am coming from an Android background). If you know what class you are using, you just have `#import` or `@class` it. I prefer this way because it makes you aware of the dependencies between classes.

Comment: It makes you aware of what you need, and this shouldn't be used of newbies, but for advanced programmer this feature is really useful and you don't have to step everytime to the top and add another new line (redundant like in other classes)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any shortcut for that. But you can Option-Click the delegate in your source code to get QuickHelp and from there you can open the Documentation with a list of all the methods in the protocol.

And usually protocol methods start always the same. For instance UITableViewDelegate methods all start with `tableView:` (like `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`). If you know that, and are only unsure about the rest, or the type of the parameters, you can simply start typing `-tableView` at the beginning of a line and XCode will list all the possible methods for you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but a plugin will do the job for you:

https://github.com/markohlebar/Peckham